# Qual è il significato di "casigliana" in questo contesto?

Tags: word-meaning, adjectives

Nel romanzo *Artemisia*, di Anna Banti, ho letto:

> Par che non s'accorga d'Artemisia, ma i dolci li posa sul davanzale. Vedo il gesto sforzato e tremulo con cui Cecilia li spinge verso l'amica, la pelle lucida della sua manina: non so come Artemisia li prenda. E vedo anche il moto di stanchezza segreta, quasi austera, che abbassa sulle pupille celesti le palpebre violette -- le ciglia son rade -- e il riaffondare delle piccole spalle nel cuscino, mentre la bocca forma un broncio infantile e poi s'inarca in una smorfia adulta di spregio, linguaggio innocente di una sofferenza troppo dura.
>
> Forse per questa smorfia, resa più delicata e altera dal soffio dell'adolescenza, Artemisia disse segretamente addio a Cecilia, un anno dopo, che in primavera "s'era fatta donna" e si cingeva stretta sotto il piccolo seno, come le ragazze *casigliane*.

Si tratta della pittrice Artemisia Gentileschi da ragazzina. L'altro personaggio che appare in questo brano è Cecilia Bari, una bambina paralitica di buona famiglia. Costretta a rimanere nella sua stanza, Cecila passa le ore affacciata alla finestra dove Artemisia va a trovarla spesso:

> La finestra del soffitone dov'è la stanza di Cecilia sporge su un balzo a dirupo che Artemisia raggiunge scendendo a salti dalla Trinità dove abita in una casupola; dei Nari, appunto.

Ho cercato il significato di "casigliano" in alcuni dizionari e ho trovato che può essere un coinquilino o qualcuno che abita in un altro appartamento della stessa casa. Tuttavia, a me non sembra che questo sia il senso di questo vocabolo nel brano precedente. Per questa ragione vi chiedo: cosa significa "casigliana" in questo contesto?

**Aggiornamento:**

Più avanti nel libro, il vocabolo "casigliana" appare di nuovo:

> Il marito di Artemisia, da piccolo, già trafficava noci, medaglie di stagno benedette, mastice per pentole rotte, statuine di cera per incantesimi e ogni genere di bagattelle. Tutto metteva in mostra sul giardino della soglia di casa, e Artemisia, ancora bambina e già sua *casigliana*, ci sputava sopra, dalla finestra.

Comment: Credo che sarebbe utile fornire qualche altro dettaglio: la parola "casigliana" è già apparsa prima nel romanzo? Che relazione c'è tra Cecilia e Artemisia? Perché Artemisia le dice addio? Che smorfia viene fatta all'inizio (è una sorta di derisione/scherno/presa in giro, oppure è qualcosa di diverso)? Per ora trovo difficile capire questa parola, indubbiamente rara e che personalmente non conoscevo.

Comment: Non è che il termine sia " castigliana"?

Comment: @PaoloFranchi: Ho cercato di farlo.

Comment: Che io sappia, è semplicemente più o meno un sinonimo toscaneggiante per “coinquilino”.

Comment: @Josh61: No, non è "castigliana", è "casigliana".

Comment: @DaG: Se, all'inizio del seicento, Artemisia Gentileschi abita con suo padre (il pittore Orazio Gentileschi) in una casupola, può avere coinquiline?

Comment: Su Google Books ho trovato questa [traduzione all'inglese del romanzo](https://books.google.es/books?id=m4Kv84zfBnMC&printsec=frontcover&dq=artemisia+banti&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjFlLz-tK7KAhULPBQKHT65BVsQ6AEICjAA#v=onepage&q=Cecilia&f=true). "Le ragazze casigliane" viene tradotto come "the other girls in her neighborhood".

Comment: A quanto pare, anche Carlo Emilio Gadda ha usato questo vocabolo nei suoi testi: http://www.gadda.ed.ac.uk/Pages/resources/glossaryindx.php.

Answer (score 3):

Per quanto possa esservi utile ho udito la parola casigliano pronunciata da mia madre con l'intento di definire il custode di una dimora signorile, in Toscana dove abito, viene usata anche la parola "casano" per identificare la stessa persona, per entrambe le parole ho trovato scarsissimi riferimenti in internet.

Answer (score 1):

Credo anch'io, come @Josh61, che l'aggettivo sia "cas*t*igliane" e aggiungo che probabilmente si tratta di un refuso - ipotesi indubbiamente azzardata e che, in quanto tale, cercherò di giustificare al meglio in quel che segue.

Facendo qualche ricerca del termine risultano presenti esempi di uso di *[donne](https://www.google.it/search?client=ms-android-google&biw=360&bih=249&tbm=bks&ei=zTyaVt-8EcmfsgGAhLTIDA&q=donne+castigliane&oq=donne+castigliane&gs_l=mobile-gws-serp.3..30i10.13255.14514.0.14983.5.5.0.0.0.0.256.998.0j3j2.5.0....0...1c.1.64.mobile-gws-serp..0.3.677.VNNwweiyEt0)*, *[fanciulle](https://www.google.it/search?q=fanciulle+castigliane&client=ms-android-google&biw=360&bih=249&prmd=ivmn&source=lnms&tbm=bks&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjO2aLQr67KAhWBXiwKHSAXDMgQ_AUICygG)* e *[ragazze](https://www.google.it/search?client=ms-android-google&tbm=bks&ei=QzeaVoy8M8uZsAG7-5_QDA&q=ragazze+castigliane&oq=ragazze+castigliane&gs_l=mobile-gws-serp.3..30i10.8305.8305.0.8790.1.1.0.0.0.0.230.230.2-1.1.0....0...1c.1.64.mobile-gws-serp..0.1.229.qFHElGa7bVs) castigliane*, in particolare in [quest'opera](https://books.google.it/books?id=_ytYAAAAcAAJ&pg=PA34&dq=ragazze+castigliane&hl=it&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwimg-3Xq67KAhWGEywKHXtZAtoQ6AEIPjAH#v=onepage&q=ragazze%20castigliane&f=false) di Byron, di cui suggerisco di leggere la pagina 34, in cui si descrive un'immagine di simili fanciulle.

Comment: Non credo che, all'inizio del seicento ed essendo di condizione sociale umile, Artemisia Gentileschi potesse seguire la moda delle fanciulle castigliane.

Comment: Per di più, la traduzione all'inglese che ho trovato (vedi il mio commento sopra) non sembra avallare questa ipotesi.

Comment: Effettivamente, in prima lettura verrebbe da pensare a "castigliane", per questo motivo chiedevo altre informazioni sul contesto. Se altrove si fa riferimento alla Spagna si potrebbe propendere per l'ipotesi del refuso, se invece c'è qualche altra occorrenza di "casigliana" questa ipotesi andrebbe esclusa

Comment: Charo, quanto alla discrepanza di tempi e condizioni economiche concordo; tuttavia avevo inteso l'aggettivo utilizzato per descrivere un modo di atteggiarsi da parte di Artemisia, non l'espressione di una moda da ella seguita.

Comment: Come ha menzionato @DaG, anche [qui](http://www.gadda.ed.ac.uk/Pages/resources/glossary/casigliano.php) si afferma che la parola "casigliano"  (e non "castigliano") è «di uso com. nella lingua parlata da’ Toscani». Questo fatto mi sembra coerente col fatto che Anna Banti, cioè Lucia Lopresti, era di Firenze. Infatti, il romanzo comincia spiegando come si sente l'autrice dopo un bombardamento del '44 su Firenze nel quale il manoscritto del romanzo *Artemisia* va perduto. Per queste ragioni,  questa ipotesi del refuso mi sembra poco credibile.

Answer (score 1):

Come suggerito da @Charo nel suo commento, attraverso il confronto con una traduzione inglese, possiamo interpretare la frase "le ragazze casigliane" con "le ragazze del vicinato", "le concittadine".

Si tratta evidentemente di uno stile molto ricercato; l'autrice sembra aver voluto estendere il significato di "casigliano" ("qualcuno che abita nella stessa casa") per includere anche "persone che vivono nella stessa città".